RuleMark annotation text is not showing properly in Charts framework SwiftUI
I tried RuleMark annotation text and it's not showing properly as truncated in attached screenshot.
import Charts
import SwiftUI

struct YAxisLabel: View {
    
    let workoutData = [
        (workoutType: "Walk", data: Workout.walkWorkout),
        (workoutType: "Run", data: Workout.runWorkout)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart {
                ForEach(workoutData, id: \.workoutType) { element in
                    // Added a optimal rule mark here
                    OptimalRuleMark()

                    ForEach(element.data) {
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Day", $0.day),
                            y: .value("Workout(in minutes)", $0.minutes)
                        )
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Workout(type)", element.workoutType))
                    .position(by: .value("Workout(type)", element.workoutType)) // Asif - this craetes grouped
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            .chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(position: .trailing) {
                    axis in
                    AxisGridLine()
                    AxisValueLabel(
                        centered: true
                    ) {
                        Text("\(axis.index * 25) min")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct OptimalRuleMark: ChartContent {
    var body: some ChartContent {
        RuleMark(
            y: .value("Optimal value", 40)
        )
        .lineStyle(.init(dash: [2, 2]))
        .annotation(
            position: .leading,
            alignment: .leading,
            spacing: 5,
            overflowResolution: AnnotationOverflowResolution(x: .fit(to: .plot), y: .fit)
        ) {
            Text("Optimal")
        }
    }
}

struct Workout: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let day: String
    let minutes: Int
}

extension Workout {
    static let walkWorkout: [Workout] = [
        .init(day: NSLocalizedString("mon", comment: ""), minutes: 23),
        .init(day: "Tue", minutes: 35),
        .init(day: "Wed", minutes: 55),
        .init(day: "Thu", minutes: 30),
        .init(day: "Fri", minutes: 15),
        .init(day: "Sat", minutes: 65),
        .init(day: "Sun", minutes: 81),
    ]
    
    static let runWorkout: [Workout] = [
        .init(day: NSLocalizedString("mon", comment: ""), minutes: 16),
        .init(day: "Tue", minutes: 12),
        .init(day: "Wed", minutes: 55),
        .init(day: "Thu", minutes: 34),
        .init(day: "Fri", minutes: 22),
        .init(day: "Sat", minutes: 43),
        .init(day: "Sun", minutes: 90),
    ]
}

Issue: RuleMark annotation label is truncating and showing last some alphabets as highlighted with red rectangle. It should show Optimal complete word as I have given in annotation Text
Could anyone please give me any suggestion to fix this issue?
I wand to show annotation text in left side then bar chart should start plotting.
I have tried below annotation with overflowResolution but still not working.
Please find the screenshot as below -


I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4. "Optimal" is placed on top of the rule mark, and the letter O aligns with the Y axis. But if I understand correctly, this is also not desirable - you want the letter L to align with the Y axis. Is that right?


I want to show annotation text in left side then bar chart should start plotting.

That sounds like this shouldn't be an annotation (so first remove the .annotation modifier), but rather part of the Y axis. Specifically, this is a value label on the left side of the Y axis.
Add a new AxisMarks to the chartYAxis:
.chartYAxis {
    AxisMarks(position: .trailing) {
        axis in
        AxisGridLine()
        AxisValueLabel(
            centered: true // are you sure you want these centered?
        ) {
            Text("\(axis.index * 25) min")
        }
    }

    // NEW:
    AxisMarks(position: .leading, values: [40]) {
        AxisValueLabel("Optimal")
    }
}

This AxisMarks should have only one value - the same value as the y value for the RuleMark.
Output:

